# sem_unlink(): permission denied on macOS

Tags: c, xcode, macos, process, semaphore

I am working on a school assignment using semaphores, every time I restart my mechine everything works as expected but after running my code, the second try gives undefined results. I've come to a conclusion that my machine don't give me permission to unlink any created semaphores, and checking the errno showed that my conclusion was correct. It gives errno EACCES, how can I fix this problem? I am working on the last visions of Xcode (12.2).

The code I am running:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h> /* For O_* constants */
#include <errno.h>

const char *semName1 = "my_sema1";
const char *semName2 = "my_sema2";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    pid_t pid;
    sem_t *sem_id1 = sem_open(semName1, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 1);
    sem_t *sem_id2 = sem_open(semName2, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
    int i, status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sem_wait(sem_id1);
            putchar('A'); fflush(stdout);
            sem_post(sem_id2);
        }
        sem_close(sem_id1);
        sem_close(sem_id2);
        wait(&status);
        int error = sem_unlink(semName1);
        int hej2 = sem_unlink(semName2);
        printf("%d \n",error);
        if (errno == EACCES){
            printf("%d \n",error);
        }
        
        
        

    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sem_wait(sem_id2);
            putchar('B'); fflush(stdout);
            sem_post(sem_id1);
        }
        sem_close(sem_id1);
        sem_close(sem_id2);
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: You need to check `sem_unlink()`'s return value to see if an error occurred with it before looking at `errno`.

Comment: And semaphore names need to start with a / character.

Comment: I've checked the value returned by sem_unlink() and it's always -1, I don't really understand what you mean by semaphore names need to start with a / character @Shawn

Comment: POSIX says *If name does not begin with the `<slash>` character, the effect is implementation-defined.* I don't know if OS X defines what the effect is if left out.

Comment: Your posted code calls `sem_unlink()` twice in a row before printing `errno` like it was the reason the first one failed, which might not be the case. You should call it once, check for and handle an error, then repeat for the other semaphore. (For **all** functions that can return an error, really)

Comment: I've tried to put a / infront of the name but apparently it does not effect anything @Shawn

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:** Run the program as *root*

**Long Answer:**

Given this code snippet:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    sem_t *sem_id1 = sem_open("sem_id1", O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
    if (sem_id1 == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("sem_open: Successful\n");

    int rc = sem_unlink("sem_id1");
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        perror("sem_unlink");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("sem_unlink: Successful\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The first time it's run, it will let you create the semaphore, but fail to unlink it:

```bash
./main
sem_open: Successful
sem_unlink: Permission denied
```

The second time it will fail even to create the semaphore:

```bash
./main
sem_open: Permission denied
```

The issue is clearly with permissions, and running the program as *root* fixes it:

```bash
sudo ./main
sem_open: Successful
sem_unlink: Successful
```

**Why does it need root privileges?**

Quoting from the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html):

> POSIX semaphores come in two forms: named semaphores and unnamed semaphores.
>
> ...
>
> **Persistence**
> POSIX named semaphores have kernel persistence: if not removed by sem_unlink(3), a semaphore will exist until the system is shut down.

These are **named** semaphores.
The fn `sem_open` and `sem_unlink` are possibly affecting processes that don't belong to you: imagine if you could run a program that overwrites or removes another process' semaphore without root permissions!